# What can you do when your question gets downvoted?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes

I had a question that started to get a few downvotes immediately after posting. I went to delete it, but got a message that said if I delete to many questions, I'll get a question ban... But if I don't delete the question, I risk getting further downvoted because I have no way of revising the question to meet SO's standards...

I don't know how many deletes I can make before question ban, but I'm not looking to test the limits.

Is there another method or best practice of stopping users from downvoting your question besides deleting it (assuming revising it is not a possibility)?

Comment: First thing, don't panic. It's not like you're some rank n00b who's racked up a half dozen heavily downvoted questions and will probably never be able to ask enough good questions to dig out. You've got a lot of questions, more upvoted than down, and that should pull things in your favour (unless you've already deleted a lot of downvoted questions). If you do trigger a ban, you have a whole bunch of deadweight zeroes in the middle that maybe you can improve upon, and those could help far more if they gathered an upvote or two than not deleting an question that's turning into a turkey.

Comment: If you're talking about your latest question, the first thing you should do is edit it to address all of the requests for clarification in the comments. You have two upvoted comments at the bottom that don't appear to have a response.

Comment: “I have no way of revising the question to meet SO's standards” - Except editing it of course but you know this since your NOT a new user.

Comment: *Why* do you have no way of revising the question to meet SO's standards?

Comment: The short answer is "write good questions." Please see the links I provided.

Comment: @SecurityHound wow, thanks for the insight /s

Comment: @PeterMortensen because SO standards are largely open to interpretation by individual users. While there are guidelines on what makes a question "good", there is no universal method of interpreting those guidelines. I wasn't referring to a specific question, but many questions I've asked have received some downvotes even though the "guidelines" were followed to a T (many are net positive, but still).

Comment: @BSMP - While I was referring to my latest question as an example (which is actually written quite well btw), my meta question was more or less just asking about questions in general. I do try to respond to every comment, but I can only do so much at one time so sometimes it takes a few minutes/hours unfortunately.

Comment: @SUMguy - Not everyone takes sarcasm with a grain of salt like I do, but I was actually pretty serious with my suggestion, if you don't want such obvious solution don't make statements like "I have no way to revise my SO questions" because we both know that isn't the case.

Comment: @SecurityHound - sorry if I wasn't clear. I was trying to playfully point out that your suggestion was in no way helpful and quite frankly was very rude.

Comment: @SUMguy - Except it wasn't rude....Your entire premises of this question, is that you wanted to delete a perfectly valid question, because you feel like could not improve it.  **I don't like seeing perfectly valid questions being deleted.** 
 Deleting perfectly valid contributions, instead of editing them, is toxic behavior in my opinion.

Comment: @SecurityHound Ahh. Well then I misinterpreted you. That's on me.

Comment: The downside: There is no incentive to revisit a question to see if its been improved and remove a downvote, so downvotes have an annoying tendency to live on past their best-before date. Don't expect a sudden positive change in the question's score. When you improve a question what you hope for is upvotes from future visitors. That can be slow going.

Answer (score 25):

Yes, there is something you can do. Read the question again. Look for things you can improve. Start with grammar and spelling. Remove anything that isn't necessary to answer the question, e.g. backstory, personal information, "thanks in advance", "hope it's clear", etc. Try to come up with a title that other people are more likely to be searching for in the future. Try to put yourself in your readers' shoes. Ask yourself these questions: Is the problem clear enough? Do they have all the needed information? Are there any other obvious issues with the code (if the question is about code) that you can fix to not distract from the main question? Can I provide an online executable to demonstrate the problem?

If after all this your question is still attracting downvotes, shrug it off and don't beat yourself about it. You tried your best. Maybe the question just isn't very useful to the community. If nobody has provided any answer yet, you can delete it but you don't have to. If there are answers available, it's best not to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

"Lack of research" is what I see in that question. No mention of [transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) anywhere. It greatly diminishes the usefulness of your question if you ask about things which have well-established solutions that pretty much anyone doing database interactions should know about.

That would essentially be the answer to the question of how to make multiple queries operate as one unit. You got an answer which combines both queries into one which is great, but it isn't what you asked for and it isn't always possible. So the next time you run into this situation, you may still be as stuck as you were with this one.

One can never explain why other people choose to downvote, but that would be the reason why I would downvote if I would run into the question in the wild.

Comment: Actually if you read the answer to the question, you would have seen that the issue was caused by a problem with the SQL interpreter, not the syntax, which I spent hours researching actually because I mistakenly assumed I had an error because I'm new to MySQL.

Answer (score -7):

Becoming a well-known unfriendly/non-interactive contributor is an option to significantly limit the number of downvotes your questions will receive as people will skip your posts.

To achieve that I do recommend writing long semi-reasonable looking posts with an ok title, good grammar and a very long way to the actual question. Ideally, you should develop easily recognizable style of titles so people don't have to rely on the name alone.

An easily recognizable user name is very important if you go this route - "SUMguy" may be enough, but you definitely need to keep the name unchanged to keep being recognized that way. Having 1000+ reputation (as you do now) is likely enough to stand out from all "new user" accounts.

Don't react to comments requesting clarification (or say something along the lines of "it is already covered in the question"). You can also consider deleting posts, but that makes it harder for others to see history and avoid interaction with your posts. It also will the lower number of people who see your questions. This can be fine if the tag is mostly visited by a small number of people from particular time zones. Unfortunately, popular tags (major languages and major DBs) have a lot of people moderating those, so deleting the post is not an ideal way to achieve such a goal.

Side note: This recommendation is based on personal experience with posters who may or may not post on SO :).

Comment: What do you mean by *"to not be piled"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen hmmm....I don't know :) that was 3am... I think I was tried to say something along the lines of "stand out enough from piles of new accounts".